# Why does the head line disappear under the logo?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, letters, line, scrlttr2

I hope somebody can help me with my problem.
I created a document as described in the last edition of the "KOMA-Script" book by Markus Kohm. My problem is that the line under the logo is almost gone and I don’t know why.

I used this logo as a PDF:

[image]

[image]

Actually I would like to have a continuous line on the head of the document (below the logo). I’ve attached the source code, I hope somebody can explain how to fix the mistake I’ve made.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,foldmarks=true, fromrule=afteraddress, fromphone, fromemail, fromlogo, version=last]{scrlttr2}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\title{KOMA_scrlttr2_Buch_S231}
%\author{ }
%\date{November 2020}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Diane Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{In der Musterstr. 10\\
                        66666 Musterstadt}

\setkomavar{fromphone}{0\,12\,34~56\,78}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{test@test.com}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=.14]{Logo/DP_Initial_Victorian01.pdf}}

\begin{letter}{%
    Max Mustermann\\
    Haupt Str. 10\\
    99999 Testhausen%
}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. 
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
\ps PS: Bitte beachten.
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlage}
\encl{Auszug aus einem Text um die Seite zu füllen}
\cc{Der Vorstand\\Geschäftsführung}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Thanks,

dplus

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Does the logo have full transparency?

Comment: The part before `\begin{document}` is missing and it's needed in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Plergux:      I used the logo as a PDF file.

Comment: @egreg:        I don't know why but the code was not copied completely. I've just corrected the code. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Zarko:        Hi, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the horizontal rule sits just *above* the baseline, so the picture overlaps it and, being printed later, it makes it invisible.

Raise the picture by the rule height (0.4pt) and you're done.

I also suggest not to use `scale`, but `height`. Smashing the picture with the optional arguments `[0pt][0pt]` to `\raisebox` makes it easier to accommodate the picture without disrupting the vertical placement of the main part of the header.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  foldmarks=true,
  fromrule=afteraddress,
  fromphone,
  fromemail,
  fromlogo,
  version=last,
]{scrlttr2}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Diane Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{In der Musterstr. 10\\
                        66666 Musterstadt}

\setkomavar{fromphone}{0\,12\,34~56\,78}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{test@test.com}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\raisebox{0.4pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=75pt]{DP}}}

\begin{letter}{%
    Max Mustermann\\
    Haupt Str. 10\\
    99999 Testhausen%
}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur 
ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque 
eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec 
pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. 
In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. 
Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. 
Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, 
eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, 
feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. 
Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. 
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
\ps PS: Bitte beachten.
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlage}
\encl{Auszug aus einem Text um die Seite zu füllen}
\cc{Der Vorstand\\Geschäftsführung}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Note: in the code I changed the name of the picture, fix it for your setup.

[image]

Comment: That’s perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can lift your logo image above rule by use of the `adjustimage` defined in the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  foldmarks=true,
  fromrule=afteraddress,
  fromphone,
  fromemail,
  fromlogo,
  version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Diane Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{In der Musterstr. 10\\
                        66666 Musterstadt}

\setkomavar{fromphone}{0\,12\,34~56\,78}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{test@test.com}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\adjustimage{margin*=0pt 8pt, 
                                   height=80pt}{example-image-duck}}

\begin{letter}{%
    Max Mustermann\\
    Haupt Str. 10\\
    99999 Testhausen%
}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\lipsum[1]

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
\ps PS: Bitte beachten.
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlage}
\encl{Auszug aus einem Text um die Seite zu füllen}
\cc{Der Vorstand\\Geschäftsführung}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Both options are very good, the results are great!